# How to add a line break seamlessly to the middle of a label value generated from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a label value in two lines. How can I add a line break to the label value in a way that would seem natural. The label is bound from a database. I currently add the label to my page like this:

```
<asp:label id="Label1" Text="<%# Eval("CompField") %> runat="server" />
```

The label can have any amount of words in it. As an example, this is a valid value that the column can produce `"Micromax Unite 2 A106 with 8 GB ROM White, with 8 GB ROM"`. So normally I would want to replace one of the spaces with a line break.

Comment: please clarify how you want to determine the break. is this one word that is overflowing from the label? Is it 2 words? Is it a random number of words? Do you know exactly what you want to break on?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the label value and what the output should look like? @KHeaney covered most of the questions I'd have asked.

Comment: For e.g this text "Micromax Unite 2 A106 with 8 GB ROM White, with 8 GB ROM" coming from Database I want to break a text and display in two lines not in a single line

Comment: Can you also clarify how you are binding to the label currently? are you just using <%# eval() %> or some other method? Also VB.NET or C#?

Comment: I'm using C# and "<%# eval() %>" this method using for Data binding

Comment: You should have a code behind that performs the DB query, processes the data so that it is ready to be displayed, and then bind to the already formatted value.

Comment: sounds like you'd be better off using css here, put the label in a div and set the div width to a set size, it'll overflow onto the next line creating your break you want.